# Set an app to be default without clearing old first

Tags: default-applications

I have unfortunately set Truecaller as the default app to view contacts.

I want the standard Google Contacts app to open contacts.

In particular, when I search for a contact on the phone using the search bar and then tap a contact, I want it to be opened in Google Contacts.

I have found plenty of advice about how to *clear* the `launch by default` setting for an app.

However, Truecaller does not think that it is the default for anything.

So, I would simply like to choose Google Contacts as the default *without clearing the original app first*.

In general I think that first having to find the old default app is a very clunky user interface. I'd like to choose the default app I want, not search for the old app. Especially when it is not clear at all which one that is.

**EDIT**
Ok, I found that it was Truedialer not Truecaller that had the defaults. But my original question is still valid: If I have difficulty finding the default app, is it possible to set a new default without clearing the old one?

Comment: There are few apps in Play Store that claims(I didn't try) to do the job(reset) for you. I found [Default App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) and [Default App Reset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pxlib.android.defaultappset).

Comment: @Firelord Default App Manager is close but unfortunately not good enough. It does not resolve the contact app default issue that is my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: Try [Better Open With](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith) app, I see they added support for dialer (I can chose from Contacts or Phone).

*Old answer: Go to Settings
Go to Apps
Select the app that is currently the default launcher for contacts.
Scroll down to “Launch By Default”.
Tap “Clear Defaults”*

Comment: My question specifically states "without clearing the original app first"

Comment: I tried the above suggested app ( Better Open With ), see it it fits your needs.